# Second order differential equation with 4 regular singular points

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I have been trying to solve the following second order differential equation:

$$\dfrac{d^{2}\Pi(r)}{dr^{2}} + P(r)\dfrac{d\Pi(r)}{dr} +Q(r)\Pi(r)=0$$

with $P(r) = \dfrac{(r\Delta(r))'}{r\Delta(r)}$, and

$$Q(r)=\frac{\left(a^2+r^2\right)^2 \left(b^2+r^2\right)^2 \left(-\frac{a \left(1-a^2\right) \text{m1}}{a^2+r^2}-\frac{b \left(1-b^2\right) \text{m2}}{b^2+r^2}+\omega \right)^2}{r^4 \Delta (r)^2}-\frac{\frac{\left(\left(1-a^2\right) (-b) \text{m1}-a \left(1-b^2\right) \text{m2}+a b \omega \right)^2}{r^2}+\lambda +\mu ^2 r^2}{\Delta (r)},$$

$$\Delta(r)= \dfrac{1}{r^{2}}(r^2 + a^2)(r^2 + b^2)(1 + r^2)-2*M = \dfrac{(r^2 - r_{0}^{2})(r^{2} - r_{1}^{2})(r^{2} - r_{h}^{2})}{r^{2}}$$

This second order differential equation possesses four regular singular points, i.e. it is a Heun Equation. I'm interested in the solution between two regular singular points, the $rh$ and $\infty$ and for this issue I was considering different methods, the shooting method and the spectral method. However when I try to compute the solution near to the singular points I get several errors.

In order to make more tractable my boundary conditions I redefine my radial coordinate by making the following transformation $z = \dfrac{r_{h}^{2}-r_{0}^2}{r^{2}-r_{0}^2}$, so the boundary is at z=0 and the horizon at z=1.

The first part is my version of the shooting method:

```
wp = 25;(*working precision *)    
Subscript[u, 1] = Π[r]
RadEqn = D[D[Subscript[u, 1], r], r] + 
D[r*Δ[r], r]/(r*Δ[r])*
D[Subscript[u, 1], 
 r] + (-(1/Δ[
    r]) (λ + μ^2*r^2 + 
     1/r^2 (a*b*ω - b (1 - a^2)*m1 - 
        a (1 - b^2) m2)^2) + ((r^2 + a^2)^2*(r^2 + 
     b^2)^2 (ω - (m1*a*(1 - a^2))/(r^2 + a^2) - (
     m2*b*(1 - b^2))/(r^2 + b^2))^2)/(
  r^4*(Δ[r])^2))*Subscript[u, 1];
Δ[r_] := 1/r^2*(r^2 - r0^2) (r^2 - r1^2) (r^2 - rh^2);
RadEqn2 = 
RadEqn /. Π -> (R[((rh)^2 - r0^2)/((#)^2 - r0^2)] &) /. 
r -> ((rh^2 - r0^2)/z + r0^2)^(1/2)
RadEqn3 = 
Collect[(-r0^2 + rh^2)^2/(4 (r0^2 + (-r0^2 + rh^2)/z) z^4)*
RadEqn2, {R''[z], R'[z], R[z]}]
```

Expansion near to a regular singular point (outer horizon, rh) and the indicial exponent

```
RadNH[z_] := (1 - z)^α
Solve[
0 == Normal[
Series[Simplify[(1 - z)^-α RadEqn3 /. {R -> RadNH}], {z, 
  1, -2}]], α] // FullSimplify
indexRule = %[[2, 1]] // FullSimplify
```

I expand at order 3 as an example,

```
order = 3;
RadH[z_] := (1 - z)^α*
Sum[cradH[nn]*(1 - z)^nn, {nn, 0, order}] /. indexRule`
coeffradH[nnn_] := 
  Coefficient[
  Normal[Series[
  Simplify[(1 - z)^(-α /. indexRule)*RadEqn3 /. {R -> RadH},
   TimeConstraint -> Infinity], {z, 1, order}]], -1 + z, nnn] // 
  Simplify
 ruleH = {};
For[iii = 1, iii < order, iii++,
  ruleH = Append[ruleH, 
  Solve[0 == coeffradH[-2 + iii] /. ruleH, cradH[iii]][[1, 1]] // 
  Simplify]
 ]
 SetDirectory["Insert the path of your working directory"]
 Save["ruleH_o3", ruleH]
```

I fixed some values like the rotation parameters and the mass...indeed my intention is to graph at the end $\omega$ vs $r_{h}$ vs $\mu$.

```
l = 0;
λ = l (l + 2);
m1 = 0;
m2 = 0;
a = 0.01;
b = 0.005;
M = 1/(2 rh^2) (rh^2 + a^2) (rh^2 + b^2) (1 + rh^2);
f[r] = 1/r^2 (r^2 + a^2) (r^2 + b^2) (1 + r^2) - 2*M;
NSolve[f[r] == 0, r] // FullSimplify
```

From the last equation I assume r0 and r1 as roots of f(r).

The results are

```
Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist. ReplaceAll::reps: {{{}}[[1,1]]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing...

RadHExpansion[z_, c0_] := SetPrecision[
RadH[z] /. ruleH /. {cradH[0] -> c0, cradH[order] -> 0}, wp]
RadHExpansion[1/2, 1] /. {ω -> 1/10, rh -> 1/10, μ -> 0}

ReplaceAll::reps
```

I also tried the horizon at 0 and the $\infty$ at 1 by making $z=\dfrac{r^{2}-r_{h}^{2}}{r^{2}-r_{0}^{2}}$, but again just errors.

For the spectral method I used an expansion in Chebyshev polynomials,

```
k = 5;
Rsub = R -> Function[z, Sum[c[n] ChebyshevT[n, 2*z - 1], {n, 0, k}]]
coeffs = Table[c[n], {n, 0, k}]
zgrid = Table[1/2*(1 - Cos[(Pi*n)/k]), {n, 0, k}] // N
Radtrunc = RadEqn3 /. Rsub // Simplify
Radtrunc /. z -> xgrid
```

I should get some equations for the coefficients of the expansion, but again that's not my case. Notice that I haven't applied the shooting or the spectral method yet, as I had already problems since the beginning.
Please any comment would be very valuable, and any help even more. Thank you!

Comment: The code ` SetDirectory["/Users/Documents/Mathematica/QNM"]` doesn't work on my machine...It's best to remove such unnecessary bits.

Comment: Dear @MichaelE2, I should have specified that there, you have to write the path where you save files, because it will generate a file once the iteration is finished. Thank you for your comment